# Python String to byte conversion

Tags: python

```
x = '192.168.1.1'
y = '255.255.255.0'
a = x.split('.')
b = y.split('.')
a[0] & b[0]
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "<pyshell#35>", line 1, in <module>
a[0] & b[0]
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'str'
```

Please help, I'd like to have the result of and-ing process between 192 and 255, between 168 and 255. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to convert the strings to integers and `&` those together

however on of the properties of 255 is that it is eight `1`s so anding it together with a smaller number is always equal to the other number

Comment: Give me an example how to convert string to integer, please :(

Comment: @user2298766 `a = map(int, x.split('.'))`

Answer (score 0):

You need to first convert the strings into integers. Try this:

```
x = '192.168.1.1'
y = '255.255.255.0'
a = [int(elem) for elem in x.split('.')]
b = [int(elem) for elem in y.split('.')]
a[0] & b[0]
```